# .NET Core Worker Service (running in Docker) cannot connect to local REST API using HTTPS

Tags: docker, ssl, .net-core

As the title states, I'm trying to figure out how I can get my .NET Core worker service deployed inside a Docker container to communicate with a REST API on my local machine (Docker host) via **HTTPS**.

**NOTE**: The Docker container is able to communicate with the REST API via plain-old HTTP just fine, so this seems to purely be an issue with HTTPS/SSL.

For background, I have a ASP.NET Core REST API deployed on my local machine via IIS. I have one binding for HTTP (port 8001) and one for HTTPS (port 8101). Additionally, said API also interfaces with my companies (model) IdentityServer instance.

Additionally, I have a .NET Core worker service which communicates with the aforementioned REST API (using an `HttpClient` under the hood). I've packaged this into a Docker image/container (using a Dockerfile, etc.).

When I run the container using the HTTP (**not** HTTPS) endpoints, everything is fine and the container is able to interface with the REST API on the local machine (provided I use `host.docker.internal` in place of `localhost` in URLs).

However, when I switch to HTTPS, things go haywire and I receive the following error:

`System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.`

I searched around for solutions but nothing seems to be working, but maybe I'm doing something wrong.

I've tried exporting (via Windows Certificate Manager) all the relevant certificates I could come up with as `.cer` files, changing their extensions to `.crt` and adding them to the Docker container via the Dockerfile:

```
COPY FooBar.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
RUN update-ca-certificates
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "My.Project.dll"]
```

(Omitted the extraneous build/publish steps as I know those are working fine, but this snippet is part of a larger multi-stage Dockerfile).

**NOTE:** `update-ca-certificates` did recognize the certificates, so I'm under the impression they were added. I thought that there might have been an issue since I'm using a multi-stage Docker build, but even adding the certificates right before the `ENTRYPOINT` seems to make no difference.

I'm honestly not sure what else it could be at this point (or if my use case is even supported).

Comment: What certificate are you using? It sounds like your issue is with the Linux OS running in the container doesn't accept your cert. A quick workaround could be to temporarily remove certificate validation from code, but it's unsafe and NOT production ready:

httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };

Comment: What I recommend instead is to either get a verified certificate for your local machine's server (something like LetsEncrypt), or trusting your locally generated cert in the Linux OS inside the container.